Apex heap size too large: 18076115 - Solution?
i'm using Tableau CRM to retrieve data and then call the method from LWC to download data into Excel
Code :
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Records>   getConsent(String  accountId, String datasetId_1, String currentVersion_1){

        List<Records> NewlstRec =  new List<Records>();
        String response ;

        String queryConsent = '';
        queryConsent =  'q = load "' + datasetId_1 +'/' + currentVersion_1 +'" ; ' ;
        queryConsent += 'q = filter q by \'AccountId\' == "' + accountId + '" ;';
        queryConsent += 'q = foreach q generate q.\'ContactName\' as \'ContactName\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Auto__c\' as \'OptInEmailAuto\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Construction__c\' as \'OptInEmailConstruction\', q.\'OptIn_Email_DeuxRouesEtQuad__c\' as \'OptInEmailDeuxRouesEtQuad\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Emprunteur__c\' as \'OptInEmailEmprunteur\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Habitation__c\' as \'OptInEmailHabitation\', q.\'OptIn_Email_MRIEtRisquesLocatifs__c\' as \'OptInEmailMRIEtRisquesLocatifs\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Plaisance__c\' as \'OptInEmailPlaisance\', q.\'OptIn_Email_RCEtMultirisquePro__c\' as \'OptInEmailRCEtMultirisquePro\', q.\'OptIn_Email_SanteDesExpatries__c\' as \'OptInEmailSanteDesExpatries\', q.\'OptIn_Email_SantePrevoyanceCollective__c\' as \'OptInEmailSantePrevoyanceCollective\', q.\'OptIn_Email_SantePrevoyanceIndividuel__c\' as \'OptInEmailSantePrevoyanceIndividuel\', q.\'OptIn_Email_SantePrevoyancePro__c\' as \'OptInEmailSantePrevoyancePro\', q.\'OptIn_Email_Voyage__c\' as \'OptInEmailVoyage\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Auto__c\' as \'OptInSMSAuto\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Construction__c\' as \'OptInSMSConstruction\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_DeuxRouesEtQuad__c\' as \'OptInSMSDeuxRouesEtQuad\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Emprunteur__c\' as \'OptInSMSEmprunteur\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Habitation__c\' as \'OptInSMSHabitation\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_MRIEtRisquesLocatifs__c\' as \'OptInSMSMRIEtRisquesLocatifs\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Plaisance__c\' as \'OptInSMSPlaisance\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_RCEtMultirisquePro__c\' as \'OptInSMSRCEtMultirisquePro\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_SanteDesExpatries__c\' as \'OptInSMSSanteDesExpatries\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_SantePrevoyanceCollective__c\' as \'OptInSMSSantePrevoyanceCollective\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_SantePrevoyanceIndividuel__c\' as \'OptInSMSSantePrevoyanceIndividuel\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_SantePrevoyancePro__c\' as \'OptInSMSSantePrevoyancePro\', q.\'OptIn_SMS_Voyage__c\' as \'OptInSMSVoyage\' ;';
        queryConsent += 'q = limit q 25000;';

        System.debug ('queryConsent #### ' + queryConsent);
        ConnectApi.LiteralJson result =  ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(queryConsent);
        
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            response = result.json;
        }
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
              response ='{"results":{"records":[{ "emailAut": "vrai" }]}}';
        }
        
        TableauCRMResponse tableauResult =  (TableauCRMResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(response, TableauCRMResponse.class);
        System.debug ('tableauResult #### ' + tableauResult);
        for(Records rc : tableauResult.results.records){
            Records rec = new Records();

            rec.ContactName = rc.ContactName ; 
            rec.emailAut = rc.emailAut ;           

            NewlstRec.add(rc);
        }
        return NewlstRec ;
}

i got an error : "Apex heap size too large: 18076115"
i tried using a batch instead , i got an error too
In tableauCRM there 23k data , why its showing 18076115  ?
Any solution?

If you can identify the data that should be part of the "download", you can have the LWC fetch it from the database in chunks. You cannot achieve this using OFFSET and LIMIT as OFFSET is at most 2000. However, if you ORDER BY Id ASC and keep track of the last ID you got, you can use Id > :lastId as part of the query, when a lastId is available. Other ordering options are available, of course, though order by ID is very easy to understand and use.

the issue is because i have 26 fields in the query .. it pass when i delete 20 for example ..

That's just impacting the payload size. So, to get all the data, get it in chunks.

i'm trying to cut the query into many queries ..

Keep it as one query, just with a deliberate ORDER BY  and LIMIT plus a WHERE clause term that allows you to identify the "next chunk" using the field in the ORDER BY to enable chunking of the results. No need to have query 1 for fields a though c and query 2 for fields d through e etc.

Does Tableau CRM have a mechanism for creating and downloading files?  It would be easier to call that instead of dealing with Apex limitations.

As per the help article,
Apex Classes:

Don't use class level variables to store a large amounts of data.
Use the Transient Keyword: Try using the "Transient" keyword with variables in your controllers and extensions. The transient keyword is used to declare instance variables that cannot be saved, and shouldn't be transmitted as part of the view state for a VisualForce page.
Construct methods and loops that allow variables to go out of scope as soon as they are no longer needed.
Keep the objects lean: If the objects in your collection contain related objects (i.e., Account objects with a number of related Contacts for each) make sure the related objects only contain the fields that are actually needed by your script.
Utilize SOQL For Loops to iterate and process data from large queries.
Use Limit Methods:

Limits.getHeapSize() - Returns the approximate amount of memory (in bytes) that has been used for the heap in the current context.
Limits.getLimitHeapSize() - Returns the total amount of memory (in bytes) that can be used for the heap in the current context.



Also review this: Error 'Apex heap size too large'
You can use batch apex to resolve this error:
global class ConsentBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, ContactName, OptIn_Email_Auto__c, ... FROM CustomObject__c WHERE AccountId = :accountId';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CustomObject__c> scope) {
        List<Records> NewlstRec = new List<Records>();
        for (CustomObject__c obj : scope) {
            Records rec = new Records();
            rec.ContactName = obj.ContactName;
            rec.emailAut = obj.OptIn_Email_Auto__c;
            // Add other fields as needed
            NewlstRec.add(rec);
        }
        // Process NewlstRec as needed
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Final processing if needed
    }
}


Batch isn't a solution , as i want when click on button the batch should be executed once its finished i want to send (huge data) to LWC which is impossible

@Fark You can use a LIMIT and OFFSET in your SOQL query to fetch a subset of records at a time. and in your LWC, call the Apex method multiple times to fetch all chunks of data. Combine these chunks on the client side.

tried it but in vain
